# Java: NoSuchMethodException with reflection when method clearly exists

Tags: java, reflection

I've been trying to use Reflection in Java, Here's my code:

```
String charsetName = "UTF-16LE";
java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder cd = Charset.forName(charsetName).newDecoder();

Class c = cd.getClass();

Class[] paramTypes = new Class[] {ByteBuffer.class, CharBuffer.class };

try {
     Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("decodeLoop", paramTypes);
     method.setAccessible(true);
     assertTrue(true);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     assertTrue(false);
}
```

Method clearly exists. 
Java source:

```
package java.nio.charset;

public abstract class CharsetDecoder {
...
   protected abstract CoderResult decodeLoop(ByteBuffer in,
                                          CharBuffer out);
...
}
```

The output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:   sun.nio.cs.UTF_16LE$Decoder.decodeLoop(java.nio.ByteBuffer, java.nio.CharBuffer)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
at com.krasutski.AppTest.testDeclaredMethod(AppTest.java:227)
...
```

if I use a parameter ***charsetName*** as

- "UTF-16LE" - Exception *NoSuchMethodException*
- "UTF-16BE" - Exception *NoSuchMethodException*
- "UTF-8" - Very good
- "cp1252" - Very good

How I'm supposed to fix this?

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? The result of the reflective invocation of `decodeLoop(in, out)` is exactly the same as using the official API call `cd.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT).decode(in, out, false)`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `getDeclaredMethod` on the *actual* type of `cd`, whereas it's *declared* in `CharsetDecoder`. That can't be the actual type of `cd` given that it's an abstract class.

Just change this:

```
Class c = cd.getClass();
```

to

```
Class c = CharsetDecoder.class;
```

The exception goes away at that point. If it's working for UTF-8 and cp1252, that suggests that the classes that are used for that *also* declare `decodeLoop`, whereas for `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16BE` they're potentially inherited.